# How to write object to the file?

Tags: python, file

I am trying to do simple student management project in python. I am trying to do write objects to the file but it does not work. And when I try to write it just writes one student and it does not write to the next line.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,age,major):
        self.fname=fname
        self.lname=lname
        self.age=age
        self.major=major

    def accept(self,fname,lname,age,major):
        ls=[str(fname),str(lname),str(age),str(major)]
        with open('student.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.writelines(ls)


obj=Student('','','','')
obj.accept('Samet','Saricicek','21','student')
obj.accept('Emre','Saricicek','24','student')
obj.accept('Ezgi','Saricicek','25','student')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
with open('student.txt', 'w') as f:
        
        f.writelines(ls)
```

you opened file in `w` that is write mode, by doing so you are removing existing content of file, if you do not wish to do that use `a` (append) mode

```
with open('student.txt', 'a') as f:
        
        f.writelines(ls)
```

See [`open` in Built-in Functions docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for further discussion of availables modes.